# How to tally count of IDs that could span multiple columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Lets say I have the following (2) tables:

**[People Table]**

**ID**      **Name**
1         John
2         Suzy
3         Dave

**[Request Table]**

**ID**    **1stChoicePersonRequested**  **2ndChoicePersonRequested**  **3rdChoicePersonRequested**  
1                        1                                                                         2                                                                        3             
2                        2                                                                       NULL                                                              NULL           
3                        1                                                                         2                                                                    NULL           
4                       3                                                                         1                                                                       1

The results I am looking  for in a query are the following:

**NameID**    **Name**      **NumTimeRequested**
1                John                        4
2                  Suzy                        3
3                  Dave                       2

I need the results to tally the *total* number of times each person was requested regardless of which of the (3) columns they are included in. What is the best way to do this in SQL 2008? Thanks!

Comment: You really ought to fix your schema, if possible. That data ought to be in a single column.

Comment: I couldn't see how to have it all in a single coulmn unless I normalized it further with just 'RequestorID', but then I would have to add something like a 'Rank' column (i.e. 1-3, etc.). It is supposed to be: "Who is my 1st choice, 2nd choice, and 3rd choice" in order of wanting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with R as
(
  select PersonID
  from [Request Table]
    cross apply (values ([1stChoicePersonRequested]),
                        ([2ndChoicePersonRequested]),
                        ([3rdChoicePersonRequested])) as T(PersonID)
)
select R.PersonID as NameID, 
       P.Name, 
       count(*) as NumTimeRequested 
from R
  inner join [People Table] as P
    on R.PersonID = P.ID
group by R.PersonID, P.Name
order by R.PersonID
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/122030/

Comment: Very nice, works great THANKS!!! Learned something new too with that 'cross apply'. I have not used that before.

Comment: One other quick question - how could I modify the query if the Requestor table had another column named 'DivisionID'. Now I need the tally the requests per person split up by division? So DivisionID = 1: John 3 Requests, DivisionID = 2: John 1 Requests ?

Comment: @atconway - If if understand correctly you have a DivisionID in [Request Table]. Add DivisionID in the CTE and in the group by clause. Have a look at this. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/122032/

Comment: That was it, THANK YOU AGAIN! This was a big help. I am just decent enough to get by with basic/intermediate reporting and CRUD using TSQL as a developer, but its not my forte. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT P.ID NameID, Name, C NumTimeRequested
FROM
    (
        SELECT ID, COUNT(*) C
        FROM (
            SELECT [1stChoicePersonRequested] ID FROM [Request Table]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT [2ndChoicePersonRequested] ID FROM [Request Table]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT [3rdChoicePersonRequested] ID FROM [Request Table]
        ) R1
        GROUP BY ID
    ) R2
    JOIN [People Table] P ON R2.ID = P.ID
```

Or, you could do this:

```
SELECT
    ID NameID,
    Name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Request Table] WHERE [1stChoicePersonRequested] = P.ID)
    + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Request Table] WHERE [2ndChoicePersonRequested] = P.ID)
    + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Request Table] WHERE [3rdChoicePersonRequested] = P.ID)    
    NumTimeRequested
FROM
    [People Table] P
```

Comment: Great help thanks! 1st version works like a charm. The problem I did have with the 2nd version though, is it brought back *all* people from the 'People' table even if they were never requested with a count = '0'.